# Change which AppDrawer is started (Google Now Launcher)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, launcher, google-now, app-drawer

I've recently installed Beautiful Drawer because I would like to categorize my Apps in the Drawer. I'm using a Nexus 5 with  Kitkat and the default Google Now launcher. My phone is not rooted.

Is it possible to change the default AppDrawer which is started when tapping on the AppDrawer-symbol on the main screen? It should start Beautiful Drawer instead of the default Drawer.

Here is a picture which shows the icon I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: I would like to launch Beautiful Drawer instead of the default drawer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The app drawer is part of the same app as the home screen itself: the *launcher* app. You can only replace both of them at once. Some launchers don't even have a separate app drawer: the list of apps is a seamless part of the home screen itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably look at App Swap drawer, launch it from Google Now gesture : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.ebt.appswitch